Why was this question about whenever the old passport is returned if one has a valid e-visa using the old passport's number closed?
I asked French passport renewal: Must the old passport be returned if one has a valid e-visa using the old passport's number?. It was closed as:

This question does not appear to be about traveling within the scope defined in the help center.

Why? Sounds about traveling to me.
The only comment explaining a close vote is incorrect:

I’m voting to close this question because such e-visas do not exist.

Such visas do exist, see Is there any e-visa that is both linked to a passport and valid beyond the expiration of that passport?, and a passport doesn't have to be expired to be replaced anyway.

The boilerplate close reasons are rather broad - we have discussed this many times. Close voters often use the close reason that is closest to what they want. And close voters are under no obligation to explain their vote - so asking for explanation is not that useful.
My close vote  matched the reason phoog gave - there only seems to be one type of e-visa (Indian) which seems unrelated to this question.
As an aside, the assumption you make in your answer here that the "closure assessment seems affected by whether the question is relevant to the voter," does not have sufficient evidence to back it up so I would discount that.

Thanks, "there only seems to be one type of e-visa (Indian) which seems unrelated to this question.": why is it unrelated? Also, as I replied to phoog in a comment, a passport doesn't have to be expired to be replaced anyway.

The question was eventually reopened. I still don't know why the question got closed originally. I can't help noticing that 4 out of the 5 reopeners are French, while afaik none of the close voters are French. It is not good that the closure assessment seems affected by whether the question is relevant to the voter.
